# Does a probabilistic model necessarily contain a random variable?

Tags: probability-theory

I am reading about the "coin tossing model" which is modeled on the space $(\Omega=[0,1],\mathcal{B}[0,1],\lambda)$ via the sequence of random variables $X(\omega)=0.\omega_{1}\omega_{2}..$

But doesn't simply the set of infinite sequences of zeros and ones provide a model for this as well? i.e without involving any random variable just having a uniform measure $P$ on $(\Omega=\{(0,1,1,1...),(0,0,1...)\}, \mathcal{F})$ where $\mathcal{F}$ is some suitable sigma algebra.

My first question is if both these model the same thing, which I think they do. My second question is, given that the first is has yes as an answer, why or when we would pick one model over another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A random variable maps $\Omega$ into the real numbers. For example, the sample space for a coin flip could be $\Omega = \{\texttt{H},\texttt{T}\}$ with $P$ the probability measure assigning probability mass $1/2$ to each outcome. However, it doesn't make sense to define expectation or variance yet. Indeed, $1/2 \cdot \texttt{H} + 1/2 \cdot \texttt{T}$ doesn't make sense. We would need to assign numeric values to the outcomes, which is what the random variable does. In your case, $X$ is just the identity map, since numbers in $[0,1]$ are already real numbers.

Comment: Is another reason for having a random variable that we can do some analysis on the model doing analysis in $\mathbb{R}$ ? i.e via the distribution

Comment: i don't understand the question. Defining the random variable in this way connects the event space on $\Omega$ to the Borel $\sigma$ algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. This is convenient because the real numbers are familiar and well studied- the application of many theorems simplifies to checking some weaker conditions when the metric space is $\mathbb{R}$, as opposed to, say, function spaces.

Comment: Sorry that was a total mess, I ment to say. Is another reason for having a random variable THAN that we can do some analysis on the model doing analysis in $\mathbb{R}$ ? i.e via the distribution

Comment: not that i know of.